# How to change method calling order in python?

Tags: python, oop, methods, operator-overloading

My question is about operator overloading in python. I want to set, the 'priority' or 'order' of the method's calling in python, and I'm looking for a pythonic way to do that. Below is a very bizarre example, but I think it will show you the point.

Let's say we want to overload the `__pos__` and the `__call__` operators in python, to make a syntax sugar on copying and modifying an object. Here is a dummy implementation on the main idea:

```
import copy

class C(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self._set(**kwargs)

    def __call__(self, **kwargs):
        self._set(**kwargs)
        return(self)

    def __pos__(self):
        return(copy.deepcopy(self))

    def _set(self, **kwargs):
        for keyword, value in kwargs.iteritems():
            setattr(self, keyword, value)

# first case:
my_obj = C(a=12, b=33, c=55)
copied = +my_obj(b=77)
print vars(my_obj), vars(copied)
# >>> {'a': 12, 'c': 55, 'b': 77} {'a': 12, 'c': 55, 'b': 77}

# second case:
my_obj = C(a=12, b=33, c=55)
copied = (+my_obj)(b=77)
print vars(my_obj), vars(copied)
# >>> {'a': 12, 'c': 55, 'b': 33} {'a': 12, 'c': 55, 'b': 77}
```

Now, as you can see, in the first case, the `__call__` method called first, and then later the `__pos__`, so the original object is modified and that modified object has been copied. The result I want is in the second case, but in that, first I had to use `()` to separate which method is called first and which is after.

So my question is: How can I change the order of calling these methods, probably in the class, without grouping the operator's calling with braces on the instance?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, the operator precedence is built into the language. I would suggest not overloading operators like this, it just makes coder harder to read.

Instead, I would argue the best option is simply:

```
copied = copy.deepcopy(my_obj)(b=77)
```

(Using `__call__()` like this also looks weird, but might be valid depending on the scenario.)

Comment: The scenario is pretty simple: I'm building a 'python-markup' language, where you will define structural hierarchy and style attributes. So it is going to be pretty handy, to write things like I mentioned above, because in this scenario, the code will be smaller, easier to read and edit. In normal circumstances, you are absolutely right: explicit is better than implicit, and I won't use these syntax sugars in my base code.

Comment: I would still argue it's a bad idea. Either use actual Python, or use a custom language. Otherwise you'll end up with this odd mix of styles and goals. I also disagree that shorter always means easier to read and edit.

Comment: Yeah.. well, lexer, parser, compiler, additional libraries.. it is a lot of work, I've done that before, and realised: what I really want is the simplicity of a markup and the power of python. That's why I chose this solution..